# Integral equation resulting from transform method - possible to express in closed form?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, integral-equations

In solving a specific problem in fluid mechanics, I have obtained a solution to a problem resembling the following. I won't provide the details of the PDEs in exact form, but I will say that I was solving two linear second-order PDEs, which are coupled and have a variety of boundary conditions. Having used a Fourier sine transform to solve the problem, I have obtained a solution of the form

$$
f(x,y)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}\left(\dfrac{\sinh\omega^{2}x}{\sinh\omega^{2}a}-\dfrac{1}{\omega^{3}}\right)f(\xi,0)\cosh\omega^{2}(x-\xi)\sin\omega y{\rm d}\xi{\rm d}\omega,\qquad\text{ in }0\le x\le a,y\ge 0.
$$

I am completely unfamiliar with integral equations, other than a very faint awareness of what they are. Does the above look like it comes from a specific family of integral equations? If so, what is it called, and what is a good starting point on where I can look if I want to obtain a closed-form solution (if indeed it is possible)?

EDIT: Integral originally contained $f(x,0)$ - it should be $f(\xi,0)$, as seen above.

Comment: I'm guessing from the context that the PDE assumes you know $f(x, 0)$, say as a boundary or initial condition, and the integral in turn gives you the values of $f$ inside the region or at a later time. Would that make sense?

Comment: As it stands the right hand side vanishes for $y=0$, so you know at least that $f(x, 0) = 0$, which in turn simplifies the situation considerably.

Comment: @Aruralreader wouldn’t $f(x,0)=0$ imply the whole integral expression $=0$? And thus $f(x,y)=0$?

Comment: @FShrike: Yep, correct.

Comment: @Aruralreader unfortunately we cannot assume that $f(x,0) =0$ beforehand. The only boundary condition on $f$ that is known in this problem is that $f_y(x,0) = 0$ (a Neumann condition). So if setting $y = 0$ makes the whole expression zero, it is likely I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @epsilond3lt4, no need to assume much at all,  it’s built into your equation. If $f$ satisfies it, plug $y=0$ into it, left and right hand sides, it and let it tell you what $f(x,0)$ has to be.

Comment: Hm, off-topic a bit, but is it possible your $f(x, 0)$ term under the integral ought to be $f(\xi, 0)$ instead?

Comment: @Aruralreader well-spotted! Does this change everything?